# LINQ: Average of a Sub IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
[
{
 "Size" : "Small",
 "Details" :
  {
    "Detail 1" : 1.0,
    "Detail 1" : 1.0,
    "Detail 2" : 1.0,
  }
},
{
 "Size" : "Small",
 "Details" :
  {
    "Detail 1" : 2.0,
    "Detail 1" : 3.0,
    "Detail 2" : 4.0,
  }
},
{
 "Size" : "Medium",
 "Details" :
  {
    "Detail 1" : 1.0,
    "Detail 1" : 1.0,
    "Detail 2" : 1.0,
    "Detail 3" : 1.0,
  }
},
//... etc
]
```

For all items with the same "Size", I'd like to individually sum up the matching "Detail" entries, and then average them across like "Size"d items.  i.e.:

```
[
{
 "Size" : "Small",
 "Details" :
 {
    "Detail 1" : 3.5,
    "Detail 2" : 2.5,     // Average of the summation of the two 'small' items in original data set
 },
    {
     "Size" : "Medium",
     "Details" :
      {
        "Detail 1" : 2.0, // Average of the two details for medium.
        "Detail 2" : 1.0,
        "Detail 3" : 1.0,
      }
    },
]
```

The code I've got is such, but I'm stuck in figuring out how to average across the nested set.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

My code, thus far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{

    class ItemWithDetails
    {
        public string Size;
        public List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> Details { get; private set; }

        public ItemWithDetails(string size)
        {
            Size = size;
            Details.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Detail 1", 1));
            Details.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Detail 1", 1));
            Details.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Detail 2", 1));
            Details.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Detail 2", 1));
            Details.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Detail 2", 1));
            Details.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Detail 3", 1));

            if (size == "Large")
            {
                Details.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Detail 3", 1));
                Details.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Detail 3", 1));
                Details.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Detail 3", 1));
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testData = new List<ItemWithDetails>()
            {
                new ItemWithDetails("Small"),
                new ItemWithDetails("Small"),
                new ItemWithDetails("Medium"),
                new ItemWithDetails("Medium"),
                new ItemWithDetails("Medium"),
                new ItemWithDetails("Large"),
                new ItemWithDetails("Large"),
                new ItemWithDetails("Large"),
            };

            // Trying to get the average of each detail, per size.

            var detailSummed = from item in testData
                               select new
                               {
                                   size = item.Size,
                                   detailsSummed = from detail in item.Details
                                                   group detail by detail.Key into detailGroup
                                                   select new
                                                   {
                                                       detailName = detailGroup.Key,
                                                       detailSum = detailGroup.Sum(a => (a.Value))
                                                   }
                               };

            var averageAcrossItems =    from item in detailSummed
                                        group item by item.size into itemGroup
                                        select new 
                                        {
                                            size = itemGroup.Key,
                                            detailsAveraged = // not sure how I can average across items, while at this level.  Do I have to flatten it?
                                        }

        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Using Adam Mills code, I've gotten closer, combining two separate LINQ Queries.  Can this be made into one LINQ query that's hopefully more readable?

```
        var detailSummed = from item in testData
                           select new
                           {
                               size = item.Size,
                               detailsSummed = from detail in item.Details
                                               group detail by detail.Key into detailGroup
                                               select new
                                               {
                                                   detailName = detailGroup.Key,
                                                   detailSum = detailGroup.Sum(a => (a.Value))
                                               }
                           };

        var test2 = detailSummed.GroupBy(x => x.size)
                                .Select(y =>
                                           new
                                           {
                                               Size = y.Key,
                                               DetailAverages = y   .SelectMany(x => x.detailsSummed)
                                                                    .GroupBy(x => x.detailName)
                                                                    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, double>(x.Key, x.Average(c => c.detailSum)))
                                           });
```

Comment: So, to be clear, you want the final sequence to contain one entry for each size, the value being the average of all items with the same size's details summed?

Comment: I think you have it right James, but to be extra clear I've updated the question with my desired output.  I want the final sequence to contain one entry for each size, and the "Details" entry to contain the average of the all the item's details, after they've been totaled per item.

Comment: If the second item was missing `Detail2: 4` would you want the resulting `Detail2` value to be `1.0` (average over items that _have_ that detail) or `0.5` (average over _all_ items)?

Comment: Rawling: .5 - average over all items.  Just curious: does that complicate things in LINQ-land?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following produces your desired output given your input, except it sums the two `detail1` values for `medium`:

```
var output = input
    .Select(iwd => new { Size = iwd.Size, Sums = iwd.Details.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key).Select(g => new { Detail = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(kvp => kvp.Value) }) })
    .GroupBy(ds => ds.Size)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.SelectMany(ds => ds.Sums).GroupBy(ds => ds.Detail).ToDictionary(dsg => dsg.Key, dsg => dsg.Sum(ds => ds.Sum) / g.Count()));
```

Note it produces a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>`.

Comment: Ooh, good catch.  I didn't realize my example end data was incorrect.  I'll have to test this out and make sure it catches all the cases, but it looks good.  Dumb question however: what's the difference between using function style notation for LINQ versus the "from x in foo" notation?

Comment: No difference, really; the query syntax (`from x in foo`) gets translated into method syntax which then gets compiled. Some things are easier to write one way, some things the other.

Comment: As you astutely asked in the comments, I do want to average across all items, not just the ones containing data.  Your solution is close, but misses the case where detail is missing from one element. Apparently Average() in this case only averages over items with this element in it?

Comment: @Eddie I've just changed this to make it "average over all" rather than "average over those with detail" when a detail is missing; make sure you double-check I'm handling that case right for you. (Ninja comment!)

Answer (score 2):

```
 items.GroupBy(x => x.Size)
                .Select(y =>

                        new
                            {
                                Size = y.Key,
                                Details = y.SelectMany(x => x.Details)
                                            .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
                                            .Select(x => new
                                                             {
                                                                 Key = x.Key,
                                                                 Average = x.Average(c => c.Value),
                                                                 Sum = x.Sum(c => c.Value)
                                                             })
                            });
```

Comment: Very close!  This is missing the summing of the details that are the same under a particular item.  I'm trying to figure that out locally... You'll likely beat me to it tho. :)

Comment: Made the detail object annonymous and added a property for the Sum and a Property for the Average

Comment: Close, but not quite.  You're averaging each individual item, versus averaging the sum.  I've posted an update to the question using your solution as a partial answer, and given you a +1 for getting me that much closer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

First some setup:

```
class ItemWithDetails {

    public string Size;
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> Details { get; private set; }

    public ItemWithDetails() {
      Details=new List<KeyValuePair<string,double>>();
   }
}
```

And the sample data to initialize;

```
var testData = new ItemWithDetails[] {
    new ItemWithDetails { Size = "Small", 
        Details = { 
            new KeyValuePair<string,double>("Detail 1",1.0),
            new KeyValuePair<string,double>("Detail 1",1.0),
            new KeyValuePair<string,double>("Detail 2",1.0),
        }
    },
    new ItemWithDetails { Size="Small",
        Details = { 
            new KeyValuePair<string,double>("Detail 1",2.0),
            new KeyValuePair<string,double>("Detail 1",3.0),
            new KeyValuePair<string,double>("Detail 2",4.0),
        }
    },
    new ItemWithDetails { Size="Medium",

        Details = { 
            new KeyValuePair<string,double>("Detail 1",1.0),
            new KeyValuePair<string,double>("Detail 1",1.0),
            new KeyValuePair<string,double>("Detail 2",1.0),
            new KeyValuePair<string,double>("Detail 3",1.0),
        }
    },

};
```

Now this query should convert the data in the way you want;

```
var q = from i in testData
        select new { 
             Size=i.Size,
             Details=i.Details
                     .GroupBy(d =>d.Key)
                     .Select(d=>new KeyValuePair<string,double>(d.Key,d.Sum(a=>a.Value)))
             } into x
        group x by x.Size into g
        let details = (
                       from a in g.SelectMany (b => b.Details)
                       group a by a.Key into g2
           select new KeyValuePair<string,double>(g2.Key,g2.Average(b=>b.Value))
                      )
       select new {
             Size=g.Key,
             Details=details
       };
```

And a little more readable, just using anonymous types instead of kvp in the answer:

```
var q = from i in testData
        select new { 
             Size=i.Size,
             Details= (
                      from d in i.Details
                      group d by d.Key into g1
                      select new {Key=g1.Key,Value=g1.Sum(a=>a.Value)}
                      )

             } into x
        group x by x.Size into g
       select new {
             Size=g.Key,
             Details=(
                       from a in g.SelectMany (b => b.Details)
                       group a by a.Key into g2
           select new {Key =g2.Key, Value= g2.Average(b=>b.Value)}
                      )
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var x =
    from item in testData
    group item by item.Size into sizeItems
    select new
    {
        Size = sizeItems.Key,
        Details =
            from item in sizeItems
            from detail in item.Details
            group detail by detail.Key into detailNumbers
            select new KeyValuePair<string, double>(detailNumbers.Key, detailNumbers.Sum(dn => dn.Value)) into detail
            group detail by detail.Key into detailNumbers
            select new KeyValuePair<string, double>(detailNumbers.Key, detailNumbers.Average(dn => dn.Value))
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var detailSummed = testData
    .SelectMany(d => d.Details.GroupBy(de => de.Key).Select(de => new { Size = d.Size, DetailSize = de.Key, Sum = de.Sum(x => x.Value) } ))
    .GroupBy (d => d.Size)
    .Select (d => 
        new 
        { 
            Size = d.Key, 
            Details = d.GroupBy (x => x.DetailSize)
                .Select(x => 
                    new KeyValuePair<string, double>(x.Key, x.Average(xi => xi.Sum)))
                .ToList()
        });
```

Lets break this down:

`d.Details.GroupBy(de => de.Key).Select(de => new { Size = d.Size, DetailSize = de.Key, Sum = de.Sum(x => x.Value) } )`
We start with the test data, and group the details into `Size, DetailSize, Sum` anonymous types. This will allow us to differentiate the different sets of `ItemWithDetails`.

`.SelectMany(d => ...`
This allows us to go from a List of Lists (Details) to a flattened list of our summarised values.

`.GroupBy (d => d.Size)`
This will group by the main items size. At this point, this groups our summarised data into all Details belonging to the main Size. We will perform our select on this grouped set of data.

```
.Select (d => 
    new 
    { 
        Size = d.Key, 
        Details = d.GroupBy (x => x.DetailSize)
            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, double>(x.Key, x.Average(xi => xi.Sum)))
            .ToList()
    });
```

This last method translates our summarised values into their respective DetailSize with the averaged values in a list of `KeyValuePair`s.